# NetBeans Language Support: CTRL-S doesn't save text file changes

Tags: java, netbeans, module, programming-languages

**The Problem**

I've been working on a NetBeans module that supports lexing/parsing for the Two Line Element data format (from here on out referred to as "TLE Files"), as described here:

https://celestrak.org/columns/v04n03/

Each TLE File follows this basic format where `N`=0-9, `C`='U' or 'S', `A`=a-Z,0-9, `+` = ' ','+', or '-', and `-` = '+' or '-'.  All other characters, including white space, must be exactly the same, and each row of data must have exactly 69 columns:

```
1 NNNNNC NNNNNAAA NNNNN.NNNNNNNN +.NNNNNNNN +NNNNN-N +NNNNN-N N NNNNN
2 NNNNN NNN.NNNN NNN.NNNN NNNNNNN NNN.NNNN NNN.NNNN NN.NNNNNNNNNNNNNN
```

My lexer and parser are implemented in terms of `org.netbeans.spi.lexer.Lexer` and `org.netbeans.modules.parsing.spi.Parser`, respectively.  Both work great and I get the syntax highlighting/error correction I initially set out to create, but one minor issue still eludes me.  When I make a change to a TLE file in the NetBeans text editor, I can't use the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd> keyboard shortcut to save my changes.  Instead, I have to select "File" --> "Save".  Any ideas on why this might be?

**Additional information**

1. I'm using my module's `layer.xml` config file to register my custom lexer/parser with NetBeans using the `languageProvider.instance` flag.
2. I'm using `org-netbeans-modules-editor-NbEditorKit` as my language's editor.
3. I have *not* added any custom actions to my module up to this point.

I'm admittedly very new to NetBeans module development, so I'm not 100% sure what information may be needed to fix this issue.  Do let me know if you think more information is needed and I'll add it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. The answer was relatively simple.  All I had to do was add the following base-level `folder` entry to the filesystem defined by my module's `layer.xml` file:

```
<folder name="Shortcuts">
    <file name="D-S.shadow">
        <attr name="originalFile" stringvalue="Actions/System/org-openide-actions-SaveAction.instance"/>
    </file>
</folder>
```